# Using File System Object with case sensitive file names

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, filesystemobject

I have a old VBScript function that save a file copy on the server from the URL. If the file already exists the function deletes the previous version and rewrites a new file version. The problem is that I need to insert case sensitive file names. For instance, the file names "Test.html" and "test.html" should be saved as different copys and my function just replaces them. Any suggestion?

The function:

```
Public Function SaveToChache(Url, SaveToFolder, FileName)
    Dim ChacheFolder: ChacheFolder = SaveToFolder 'Folder where will the cache files be   stored (include trailing slash)
    Dim FilePath: FilePath = Server.MapPath(ChacheFolder & FileName)
     Dim objXMLHTTP: Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
     objXMLHTTP.open "GET", Url, false
     objXMLHTTP.send()
     If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then 
         Dim objADOStream: Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
         objADOStream.Open
         objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
         objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
         objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start
         Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.FileExists(FilePath) Then objFSO.DeleteFile FilePath
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        objADOStream.SaveToFile FilePath
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing
        SaveToChache = objXMLHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
    Else
        SaveToChache = ""
    End if
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Calling the function:

```
savefile = SaveToChache("http://www.example.com", "/cache/", "Test.html")
```

Thanks!

Comment: See the answers to [this question on SU](http://superuser.com/q/266110) for an explanation of why this is possible in principle, but usually not feasible in practice (and arguably not even desirable).

Comment: So, changes have to be made in the server settings?

Comment: In the kernel configuration, yes.

Comment: I'd rather make a kludge by including a random number before the file name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a direct compare instead of `objFSO.FileExists`.

for example:

```
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FilePath = "C:\Test\test.txt"

'Get path to file
strParentPath = objFSO.GetFile(FilePath).ParentFolder
'Get each file in the folder
Set objCheck = objFSO.GetFolder(strParentPath).Files

For Each x In objCheck
    If x = FilePath Then objFSO.DeleteFile(FilePath)
Next
```

Basically, x will only equal FilePath if the case is also the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, it dont work for me! I'm getting ADODB.Stream erro '800a0bbc' error.